# How To send JSONArray Array with JSONObject object from One activity to Second Activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I receive JSONArray from Server I create new Jsonarry with Jsonobject which I want to send to another activity I received it another activity when I get data from jsonarray it through exception

JSOn Array

```
{"restaurant_name":[{"restaurantname":"Tikka Mehal","fooditemname":"Chicken Fajita Pizza","fooditemprice":"800"},{"restaurantname":"Saege","fooditemname":"Chicken Fajita Pizza","fooditemprice":"800"}]}
```

AsynTask Class

```
        JSONObject sending_object = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray sending_array = new JSONArray();

        else
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurant_name");
            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                sending_array.put((jsonObject1.getString("restaurantname")));
                sending_array.put(jsonObject1.getString("fooditemname"));
                sending_array.put(jsonObject1.getString("fooditemprice"));
            }

            sending_object.put("restaurant_name",sending_array);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,RestaurantFoodItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("restaurant_names",sending_object.toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Activity Two

ArrayList restaurants;

```
 Intent bundle = getIntent();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(bundle.getStringExtra("restaurant_names"));
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurant_name");
        for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);// there through exception
            String r_name = jsonObject1.getString("restaurantname");
            String f_name = jsonObject1.getString("fooditemname");
            String f_price = jsonObject1.getString("fooditemprice");
            restaurants.add(new Restaurant(r_name,f_name,f_price));
        }
```

Comment: can you post error logs

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value Tikka Mehal at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject this was error

Answer (score 0):

Use Parcelable or Serializable interface.
Try with encapsulating json data in Some Restaurant Object which is implementing Parcelable.
Example :

```
public class Person implements Parcelable {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private List<Person> konwnPersons;
private List<String> qualifications;



public Person() {
    super();
}

public Person(Parcel parcel) {
    this.firstName = parcel.readString();
    this.lastName = parcel.readString();
    this.qualifications = parcel.readArrayList(null);
    this.konwnPersons = parcel.createTypedArrayList(Person.CREATOR);
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

 public List<String> getQualification() {
    return qualification;
}
public void setQualifications(List<String> qualifications) {
    this.qualifications = qualifications;
}

public List<Person> getKonwnPersons() {
    return konwnPersons;
}

public void setKonwnPersons(List<Person> konwnPersons) {
    this.konwnPersons = konwnPersons;
}


public static final Creator<Person> CREATOR = new Creator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public Person createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Person(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Person[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Person[size];
    }
};


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.firstName);
    dest.writeString(this.lastName);
    dest.writeList(this.qualifications);
    dest.writeTypedList(this.konwnPersons);

}
}
```

Now for sending data use this :

```
Intent secondActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setFirstName("Rajnish");
                person.setLastName("Suryavanshi");
secondActivityIntent.putExtra("data",person);
                startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
```

For Retrieving data use :

```
Person person = (Person)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
```

Comment: here i need object on zero index all data then object on index 2 need all data

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value Tikka Mehal at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject this was error I also try to get data from JsonArray but not work

Comment: you want to send list of data?

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe exception is because you just putting string in json array and not json object and in your next activity you are try to get jsonObject from array which is not there you can make following changes

```
else
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,RestaurantFoodItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("restaurant_names",jsonObject .toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

> if you keep same code in second activity it should work

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value Tikka Mehal at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject this was error

Comment: I change it from String to (Serializable)

Comment: it not working when I remove toString do you tell me how I send Jsonobject using intent

Comment: you don't need to remove toString ; just remove those for loop and pass the jsonObect as is to activity two

Comment: I am use for loop because I reveiving json array from Server so I get all data from and add it to new json array

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use HashMap ?

For example, when sending the intent:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new    HashMap<String, String>();
hashMap.put("key", "value");  
Intent intent =
new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);          

startActivity(intent);
```

And then in the receiving Activity:

```
HashMap<String, String> 
hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
```

**Edit**

After reading your comment , i thing the best approach is to use a database and store your informations once you get them ,and then use them in your second activity

Comment: I have several object and each objects have three values so